# Capacitor Reactance/Impedance Confusion

Tags: capacitor, reactance

I always thought that capacitors (when used in phasor analysis) just had an impedance of $$1/jwc$$.

I understand that impedance $$Z=R+jX$$where R is resistance and X is reactance.
Now, in one book I found that the reactance of a capacitor is $$1/wc$$. So the impedance for the capacitor would be $$j/wc$$.

How come it's j/wc here and we always used 1/jwc before??

[image]

Comment: 1/j = -j so 1/(jwc) = -j/(wc)

Comment: Yeah but that has a minus sign. In the book it just has 1/wc as the reactance for a capacitor. So if I sub that into Z = R+jX. I get Z = j/wc not -j/wc

Comment: Well, maybe the book is referring to just the magnitude of the reactance since we know what the angle is for a pure capacitance.

Comment: Oh yeah, you could be right there. I'll take it then that in general X_C is - 1/wc

Comment: Yes, reactance is the magnitude of the impedance. Reactance is always a real number and always positive.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, if you're going to always express reactance as a positive number, you need to specify "capacitive reactance" or "inductive reactance">

Comment: @ThePhoton Fair enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some authors specify the reactance of basic circuit elements as an absolute value. Although this is confusing it is not so uncommon. The "trick" is to remember that if you *define* reactances as:

\[
X_L = \omega L \qquad X_C = \frac{1}{\omega C}
\]

***then*** the impedance for an inductor and a capacitor are:

\[
Z_L = j X_L = j \omega L
\qquad
Z_C = -j X_C = \frac{- j}{\omega C} = \frac {1}{j \omega C}
\]

The problem with this approach is that you must always remember that the reactance as the imaginary part of a generic impedance (i.e. X = Im(z)) is *not* the same reactance you speak of when talking about "pure" capacitors (there the sign of the reactance is embedded in the value of X).